# [Scala]: Problem with Actors and blocking IO

Tags: scala, io, blocking, actor

I'm having a little problem with Scala Actors and blocking IO. I'm using an actor that itself has an anonymous actor that consumes an input stream. The problem is that this stream only reads one line and then blocks without waking up again. What confuses me is that it worked when the consumption took place in the act method (coincidence?). The application itself has some more actors and java threads doing some work.

My question is: What is the common practice to avoid such problems? Any pointers?

The code that causes this problem looks somewhat like this:

```
object TestActor extends Actor {

  private val instream = actor {
    loop {
      try {
        println(processInput(input.readLine)) //bufferedinputstream. blocks, no wakeup
      } catch {
        case e: Exception =>
          println(e.toString)
      }
    }
  }


  def act(): Unit = {
    react {
      ...
      case _ => {}
    }
  }
}
```

Regards,
raichoo

Comment: Why are you using an actor instead of a Java thread?  You aren't taking advantage of any of the actor-specific capabilities, and you want it to run always.  That's exactly what a thread does.  Just override the run method and put your try block in there.

Comment: Where are you getting everything from? Where's "input" declared? Who owns "processInput"? Actors is about behavioral response to _messages_, I see no messages at all in your example.

Comment: I obviously was so dead set on using actors for this that I didn't see the obvious here. Thanks for bringing me back on track.

Answer (score 1):

The call to readLine is inside loop{} so it's going to happen over and over until it blocks.